# Setting Up Stand-alone LanguageTool in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, languagetool

Im trying to setup LanguageTool as a standalone server as a Docker Container. So what I did is download the standalone system provided at -> https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-stable.zip and put it in my project. I setup the docker-compose.yml file like so

```
version: '3'
services:
   grammar:
    build: ./services/grammar
    image: dev/grammar:1
    restart: always
    container_name: dev.grammar
    ports:
      - "8130:8130"
```

And I created the dockerfile inside the LanguageTool folder like so

```
FROM  ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install unzip

ADD https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-stable.zip /tmp/LanguageTool-stable.zip

#RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN unzip /tmp/LanguageTool-stable.zip
RUN mv /tmp/LanguageTool-5.7 /usr/languagetool
  
CMD ["java", "-jar", "languagetool-server.jar", "--port", "8130", "--public", "--allow-origin", "'*'" ]
EXPOSE 8130
```

I have actually tried many iterations of the dockerfile like another example here

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN set -ex \
    && mkdir -p /uploads /etc/apt/sources.list.d /var/cache/apt/archives/ \
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
        bash \
        curl \
        openjdk-8-jre-headless \
        unzip \
        libhunspell-1.4-0 \
        hunspell-de-at
 
ENV VERSION 5.7
COPY LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip /LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip

RUN unzip LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip \
    && rm LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip
 
WORKDIR /LanguageTool-$VERSION

CMD ["java", "-cp", "languagetool-server.jar", "org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer", "--port", "8130", "--public", "--allow-origin", "'*'" ]
EXPOSE 8130
```

But none of them seems to work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance !!

Edit: Here is what my file/folder structure looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTzTV.png)

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what does happen?  The first variant doesn't contain a JVM (and you might start from something like an `openjdk` image) but the second looks plausible.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DavidMaze. Here is the error I get 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer.

I think my Dockerfile is messed up. Please help me correct it. Thanks!

Comment: Also please take a look at the file structure I'm going with -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTzTV.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Had to tinker around some configurations but I finally got it working. here is the dockerconfig file that worked for me.

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN set -ex \
    && mkdir -p /uploads /etc/apt/sources.list.d /var/cache/apt/archives/ \
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
        bash \
        curl \
        openjdk-8-jre-headless \
        unzip \
        libhunspell-1.4-0 \
        hunspell-de-at
 
ENV VERSION 5.1
COPY LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip /LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip

RUN unzip LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip \
    && rm LanguageTool-$VERSION.zip
 
WORKDIR /LanguageTool-$VERSION

CMD ["java", "-cp", "languagetool-server.jar", "org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer", "--port", "8130", "--public", "--allow-origin", "'*'" ]
EXPOSE 8130
```

Comment: So it looks like the only thing you changed was going from "ENV VERSION 5.7" to "ENV VERSION 5.1"?  Or was there a change in your file structure?

Comment: yeah the file structure is pretty much the same. Just changing around the dockerfile worked. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: I found https://github.com/Erikvl87/docker-languagetool which looks like a good base, using the current version from git.  I'll probably use that.    Was there a reason you rolled your own instead?